# How to confgure custom html tags alternative with googel tag manager server side

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I am in process of migrating a web tag container to a server side google tag container and not able to figure out following -

- How to configure Custom html tags available in web container to server side container?
- Do I have to keep all my custom html tags as it is in web container itself?
- Can a GA event some how be transformed to custom html tag so that it can be processed by GTM server side container.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your html tag contain some 3rd party tracking js or library?

In server-side, it is not operate the same way as your web container.

Server-side only can send request to those 3rd party. Here is an example.

note: There is a template in server-side container for facebook already, but this example just want to explain the difference between web container and server-side.

---

#### Facebook Pixel

In web container, we load a `pixel.js` from facebook.

And Just call `fbq('track', 'PageView')`

then facebook will receive a `request` about all information they need.

---

In server-side, we can not just call `fbq` function

We need to assemble the `request` or use some template that other already done.

Here is a example request from `fbq('track', 'PageView')`

```
https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=pixel_id
&ev=PageView
&dl=xxx
&rl=
&if=false
&ts=1679712182424
&sw=2560
&sh=1440
&v=2.9.100
&r=stable
&ec=0
&o=30
&cs_est=true
&fbp=fb.1.xxx.yyy
&it=xxx
&coo=false
&tm=1
&rqm=GET
```

There are more detail about the facebook CAPI.

But hope this can give you some direction about the difference between server-side container and web container.

All other tracking or tagging platform or system are quite the same.
The only platforms that are easy to do are google related (GA4, UA, GoogleAds).

Comment: Yes; Custom html tags contain 3rd party JS code; and I couldn't find any template in server side tag container.
Thanks for insight; I will try to figure out if I have to go with web container itself for those tags.